# How to insert shopping cart date into database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, shopping-cart

I'm doing an online Food Ordering System and it has the add to cart function. Below is my cart function code. I would like to insert the data added into the cart by customer into the database to be viewed by the admin or staff to prepare the order. I have no idea how to make it work. I am very new to PHP and this is my first project. Please kindly help me..

```
function cart() {
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value){
    if ($value>0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_'){
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products    WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ RM '.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = RM '.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br /><br />';
                }
            }
            $total += $sub;
        }

    } 
    if ($total==0) 
    {
        echo "Your cart is empty.";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Total: RM'.number_format($total, 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: I will answer this question...but wait..is that you on the picture?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO products `id`,`name`,`price` VALUES('{$id}','{$name}','{$price}),('{$id}','{$name}','{$price}')
```

etc for each item

of course you escape the values and I am also assuming the id is auto incremented

Comment: yeah, but could it be added into the database if there is more than one item in the cart.

Comment: you mean to add individual items from cart?

Comment: if i'm understanding you correctly you want to do a checkout of all items? in that case you can just put it in a loop for every item you wish to process.

Comment: Yes, after the customers select the item they need and add it all to the cart, they need to press a button which would insert the data of the items the customer want into the database so that the staff could prepare the order by retrieving the information from the database..i have completed all the cart code, I just don't know how to insert the items in the cart to the database.

Comment: but again if the id is autoincremented which it should be then you should leave that out of the statement. multiple rows can be put in by separating a comma between the value sets. I updated the code above in case you didn't catch it :)

Comment: how is the data viewed on other end? you could have the db table have a column called 'order_id', or something to that effect

Comment: also, theres an auto-timestamp feature for adding records in sql